# javascript:submitform() using a python script

Tags: javascript, python

let's say I want to make a script that auto-sends a request to this site: http://makemehost.com/
So I can host maps without inserting each and every parameter every time.

I looked around for a long time, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Could any of you help with that? 
Not asking to be spoon-fed, just to be directed.

Thanks in advance